# Log4j write to yesterday file? How to fix?

Tags: log4j

I have a question about log4j configuration, wish supported from all of you
Below is my log4j config, I want to separate file by date.

```
log4j.logger.service.common.KPILog=ALL, KPILog
log4j.additivity.service.common.KPILog=false
log4j.appender.KPILog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.KPILog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.KPILog.MaxFileSize=1GB
log4j.appender.KPILog.Append=true
log4j.appender.KPILog.File=/var/log/dpjp/kpi.log
log4j.appender.KPILog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.KPILog.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

Today is January 23, but when I tail log, the kpi.log is nothing happen, but it append to kpi.log.2014-01.22

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I have already fix this issue. 
The problem is that in my system, it's many application servers and point logging to a file. So when server 1 change logging file by date, the another doesn't know it, so they still pointing to the old file (now the old file has new file name: kpi.log_yesterday). Maybe the later servers check logging flag from log4j, it's switched by first server, so they doesn't change again => they still point to old file.

My solution is each server write to each file. So all is OK.